# Grep for 3.07 using regex

Tags: regex, grep

I am attempting to search for 3.07 in a log file however I'm having difficulty with the correct regex. I have tried the following but this returns values matching 3.0 or 3.7:

```
grep '[3]\.[07]' GDCBAdapter.log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No regex is required at all. You can simply search for fixed strings using `-F`:

```
grep -F '3.07' GDBCAdapter.log
```

[`man grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple, you just have to:

```
grep '3\.07' GDCBAdapter.log
```

No need for character class, i.e `[07]` as it matches 0 OR 7.

Answer (score -2):

Just realised:

```
grep '[3]\.\08' GDCBAdapter.log
```

Comment: Why 3 is inside a class?

Comment: Cause I was copying it from elsewhere and forgot to remove it. Still had the same end result but not too efficient I guess.